# If L is regular language then each equivalence class is also regular?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

L is a regular language. Let's say that E is one of L's equivalence classes - is it true/false that E is also regular?

The equivalence relation is, from Wikipedia: "Given a language L, and a pair of strings x and y, define a distinguishing extension to be a string z such that exactly one of the two strings xz and yz belongs to L. Define a relation RL on strings by the rule that x RL y if there is no distinguishing extension for x and y."

Comment: What is the equivalence relation used to define the equivalence classes?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Given a language L, and a pair of strings x and y, define a distinguishing extension to be a string z such that exactly one of the two strings xz and yz belongs to L. Define a relation RL on strings by the rule that x RL y if there is no distinguishing extension for x and y." It's all related to Myhill Nerode theorem.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all relevant information in the question, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a DFA $D$ and a word $x$, let $D(x)$ denote the state of $D$ after reading $x$.

Let $D$ be a minimal DFA for $L$ and $x,y \in \Sigma^*$.
If $D(x) \neq  D(y)$ then $x$ and $y$ have a distinguishing extension.
Indeed, if $x$ and $y$ had no distinguishing extension, it would be possible to construct a DFA $D'$ with one less state by merging the states $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ of $D$.

On the converse, if $D(x)=D(y)$ then $x$ and $y$ have no distinguishing extension (since the states reached by $D$ from $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ after reading any string $z$ must coincide).

Then, $x$ and $y$ are in the same equivalence class iff $D(x)=D(y)=q$, for some state $q$ of $D$.

Given a state $q$ of $D$, the language of all the words $x \in \Sigma^*$ such that $D(x)=q$ is regular. To see this, consider the DFA obtained from $D$ by changing the set of final states to $\{q\}$.

Comment: Thanks! But if I'm not wrong, you proved that the language which contains all words in L such that D(x) = q is regular. But an equivalence class doesn't necessarily a subset of L. Why in first place you took x,y in L and not some random words? (which are not necessarily in L)

Comment: The same holds if you consider $x,y \in \Sigma^*$. In your question you specified the equivalence relation $\rho$ but you didn't specify the quotient set, so I had assumed the equivalence classes were those in $L / \rho$. I understand now that you are interested in $\Sigma^* / \rho$ instead.

Comment: Yeah, I need to learn how to write math symbols in here so I'd be more precise :) Thanks for the help!